# Comme nous avons évoqué ou bien comme évoqué

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Je suis en train de rédiger un mail suite à une conversation qui a eu lieu il y a quatre semaines avec un client.

> Bonjour X,
>
> Comme nous avons évoqué, lors de notre denier call.

ou bien

> Comme évoqué, lors de notre denier call.

C'est quoi la bonne forme à utiliser ?

Comment: evoquer is "intransitif" .. so it depend on the rest of your sentence : "Comme nous avons évoqué, lors de notre dernier call, les prestations de décembre, je dois vous en reparler aujourd'hui." could be acceptable, or "Comme evoqué, lors de notre dernier call, les presations de decembre sont en hausses" .. in the second, "les prestations de decembre" are not a complement .. but a subject ..

Answer (score 1):

La phrase ne peut pas être terminée après *call* et la virgule ne se justifie pas.

> Comme nous l'avons évoqué lors de notre dernier call,...

> Comme évoqué lors de notre dernier call,...

On peut bien sûr remplacer *call* par « appel », « conférence », « réunion », « atelier » ou tout autre mot décrivant de quoi il s'agissait.

Comment: Atelier à la place de call ? ou réunion ?

Comment: Pourquoi pas, du moment que ça décrit bien de quoi il s'agissait.

Comment: I agree with @jiliagre : "call" is not correct french, but nevertheless it's often used, and languages are alive and evolving